# DocuSign: PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. Invalid account specified for user

Tags: php, docusignapi

So I've been trying to get the php EnvelopesApi working. I've got JWT auth running and I can get an access token. Calling the EnvelopesApi::createEnvelope method returns

`400 PARTNER_AUTHENTICATION_FAILED The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. Invalid account specified for user.`

Now I've read a lot about this and it seems to be fixed by making sure either:

- Host is correct
- Integrator key matches the same key used in generating access_token
- Making sure to use the correct impersonated_user_id associated with the integrator key

I've tried everything and it is always returning with the same response. Anyone have an ideas?

```php
    /**
     * DocuSign login handler
     */
    public function getAccessToken()
    {

        $apiClient = new ApiClient(new Configuration());

        $apiClient->getOAuth()->setOAuthBasePath($this->config['authorization_server']);
        $privateKey = file_get_contents($this->config['private_key_file'], true);

        try {

            $response = $apiClient->requestJWTUserToken(
                $this->config['integration_key'],
                $this->config['ds_impersonated_user_id'],
                $privateKey,
                $this->config['jwt_scope']
            );

            $this->accessToken = $response[0]->getAccessToken();

            $this->userInfo = $apiClient->getUserInfo($this->accessToken)[0]->getAccounts();

            $this->baseUri = $this->userInfo[0]->getBaseUri();

            return $this->accessToken;

        } catch (\Throwable $th) {

            return false;

        }

    }



    public function generateDocument(array $fields)
    {

        return file_get_contents($this->config['pdf_template']);

    }


    public function createEnvolope($document, $name, $email)
    {

        $base64FileContent = base64_encode($document);

        # Create the document model
        $document = new Document([ # create the DocuSign document object
            'document_base64' => $base64FileContent,
            'name' => 'Example document', # can be different from actual file name
            'file_extension' => 'pdf', # many different document types are accepted
            'document_id' => 1 # a label used to reference the doc
        ]);

        $recipientId = rand(10000000, 99999999);
        // $clientUserId =  rand(10000000, 99999999);

        # Create the signer recipient model
        $signer = new Signer([ # The signer
            'email' => $email,
            'name' => $name,
            'recipient_id' => $recipientId,
            'routing_order' => '1',
            # Setting the client_user_id marks the signer as embedded
            // 'client_user_id' => $this->config['ds_impersonated_user_id'],
        ]);


        # Add the tabs model (including the sign_here tab) to the signer
        # The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
        $signer->settabs(new Tabs([
            'sign_here_tabs' => [
                new SignHere([ # DocuSign SignHere field/tab
                    'anchor_string' => '/sn1/',
                    'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
                    'anchor_y_offset' => '10',
                    'anchor_x_offset' => '20'
                ]),
            ]
        ]));

        # Next, create the top level envelope definition and populate it.
        $envelope = new EnvelopeDefinition([
            'email_subject' => "Please sign this document sent from the PHP SDK",
            'documents' => [$document],
            # The Recipients object wants arrays for each recipient type
            'recipients' => new Recipients(['signers' => [$signer]]),
            'status' => 'sent' # requests that the envelope be created and sent.
        ]);

        return $envelope;

    }


    public function sendEnvolopeToDocuSign($envelope)
    {

        # Call Envelopes::create API method
        # Exceptions will be caught by the calling function
        $config = new Configuration();
        d($this->accessToken);
        $config->setHost($this->userInfo[0]->getBaseUri() . '/restapi');
        // $config->setHost('https://account-d.docusign.com/restapi');
        $config->addDefaultHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $this->accessToken);

        $apiClient = new ApiClient($config);
        $this->api = new EnvelopesApi($apiClient);

        try {

            return $this->api->createEnvelope($this->userInfo[0]->getAccountId(), $envelope);

        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            d($th->getMessage());
            return false;

        }

    }
```

COnfig:

```
$JWTConfig = [
'api_base' => 'https://demo.docusign.net',
'integration_key' => '5dec4fd0-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
'authorization_server' => 'account-d.docusign.com',
'ds_impersonated_user_id' => '4cc86c57-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx',
'jwt_scope' => 'signature impersonation',
'private_key_file' => __DIR__ . '/../ds_private_key.key',
'pdf_template' => __DIR__ . '/../docusign_template.pdf',
```

];

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that you're having this problem.

Next step to fix is to examine the complete error response to see the additional reason code. If your software doesn't show you the error response's body, then use [API logging](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging) to see the complete response.

Then use this [article](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-from-the-trenches-may-2020) for further debugging help on this error.

#### The specified Integrator Key was not found or is disabled. Invalid account specified for user

As noted in the article this can mean:

**Wrong base url** -- but since you're using demo, and there's only one demo system, that's not the issue.

**Wrong account id** -- the wrong account id is being used in the API call.

Check that the impersonated user has access to the account id that you're using in the API call. The best way to do this is to call the [/oauth/userinfo](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/reference/user-info/) API method. This should be done, once, after you first obtain the access token from the JWT grant.

Calling /oauth/userinfo with the access token gives you valuable information:

- Assures you that the access token is working
- Gives you the name of the person impersonated
- Gives you the account id or account ids that the person has access to

Note that the host for /oauth/userinfo is the IdP. For demo, it is `https://accounts-d.docusign.com`